# Efficient way to generate nested html sitemap in django with lower SQL queries

Tags: python, django

It is very common to use recursive method and it is the trivial answer. it make queries as much as count of pages.
is there another way to create such html sitemaps with lower queries?

```
def rec_print_childs(page):
   print "<ul>"
   for child in page.childs:  # childs is related_name in page module for parent field
       print "<li>"+child.name
       rec_print_childs(child)
       print "</li>"
   print "</ul>"

rec_print_childs(parent_node)
```

Comment: Where are the queries? What is parent_node?

Comment: @Bilou06 the query is in `for child in page.childs:`

Comment: Did you try this https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/models.html ?

Comment: @Bilou06 thanks, I was read its docs before and know about it, it is very smart! but I have this ORM and converting to MPTT will cost me difficulties now and in maintenance-time.

Comment: I think you hit a limitation of SQL. If you can't modify your model to use mptt, you must do a lot of queries or query anything and solve dependencies "by hand"